# Using an 'old' .keystore file for my updated Flutter app

Tags: flutter, keystore, google-play-console

I have an app in the Play Store which is built using Phonegap. It used a .keystore file for signing. I rebuilt the app in Flutter but as I understand, Flutter requires a .jks file for signing.

When I create a new Keystore (.jks) the Play Console won't upload the App Bundle because the key is different (obviously).

How to fix this?

Comment: I hope this link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49924556/convert-keystore-to-jks-to-sign-apk

Comment: Not solved yet, but it definitly pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!